# How do I delete a Git remote branch from the NetBeans IDE?

Tags: git, netbeans, ide, branch

How do I delete a Git remote branch?

I work with NetBeans, and I tried to delete a remote branch from IDE, but on the delete branch it deleted only locally.

Comment: Maybe it is not possible to do it in your NetBeans version: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209644

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can also use

---

```
git push origin --delete <yourBranchName>
```

Answer (score 14):

```
$ git push origin :name-of-your-branch
```